# C++ Class rectangle assign values

Tags: c++, pointers, floating-point, return-value

I'm writing a class rectangle for this assignment Create a class Rectangle with attributes length and width, each of which defaults to 1. Provide member functions that calculate the perimeter and the area of the rectangle. Also, provide set and get functions for the length and width attributes. The set functions should verify that length and width are each floating-point numbers larger than 0.0 and less than 20.0.

I keep getting an error advising setLengthandWidth, setLength, and setWidth must return a value. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any advice? Here are my 3 files.

Header file

```
#ifndef Rectangle_H
#define Rectangle_H
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle();
    Rectangle(float length);
    Rectangle(float length, float width);
    ~Rectangle();
    float setLengthAndWidth(float, float);
    float setLength(float Length);
    float setWidth(float Width);
    float calculatePerimeter();
    float calculateArea();
    void printInfo();
    float getLength();
    float getWidth();
private:
    float length;
    float width;
    float area;
    float perimeter;
};
#endif#pragma once
```

main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include "Rectangle.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Rectangle objectOne;
    Rectangle objectTwo(7.1, 3.2);
    Rectangle objectThree(6.3);
    Rectangle objectFour(200, 300);
    Rectangle objectFive = objectTwo;
    cout << "The first objects information is\n  ";
    objectOne.printInfo();
    cout << "The second objects information is\n  ";
    objectTwo.printInfo();
    cout << "The third objects information is\n  ";
    objectThree.printInfo();
    cout << "The fourth objects information is\n  ";
    objectFour.printInfo();
    cout << "The fifth objects information is\n  ";
    objectFive.printInfo();
}
```

member .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include "Rectangle.h"
using namespace std;
Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
    length = width = 1.0;
}
Rectangle::Rectangle(float length)
{
    setLengthAndWidth(length, 1.0);
}
Rectangle::Rectangle(float length, float width)
{
    setLengthAndWidth(length, width);
}
float Rectangle::setLengthAndWidth(float Len, float Wid)
{
    setLength(Len);
    setWidth(Wid);
}
float Rectangle::setLength(float length)
{
    if (length >= 0 || length <= 20.0)
        length = length;
    else
        length = 1.0;
}
float Rectangle::setWidth(float width)
{
    if (width >= 0 || width <= 20.0)
        width = width;
    else
        width = 1.0;
}
float Rectangle::calculatePerimeter()
{
    perimeter = (length * 2) + (width * 2) ;
    return perimeter;
}
float Rectangle::calculateArea()
{
    area = length * width;
    return area;
}
float Rectangle::getLength()
{
    cout << "Please enter length" << endl;
    cin >> length;
        return length;
}
float Rectangle::getWidth()
{
    cout << "Please enter width" << endl;
    cin >> width;
    return width;
}

void Rectangle::printInfo()
{
    cout << "the length is " << length << endl << "the width is " << width << endl;
    cout << "the perimeter is " << perimeter << endl << "the area is " << area << endl;

}
Rectangle::~Rectangle()
{
    cout << "the object has gone out of scope. ";
}
```

Comment: `length and width are each floating-point numbers larger than 0.0 and less than 20.0` is different to `if (length >= 0 || length <= 20.0)`, change the above to: `if (length >= 0 && length <= 20.0)`

Comment: There's something wrong with the type signature of those functions... `float Rectangle::setLengthAndWidth(float Len, float Wid)`.

Comment: If it were me who wrote the assignemnt, all the functions would be const, and I would avoid mutating the instances because it's a well too low level optimization which can lead to trouble (like mutating a shared instance). Thus the setter would have to instantiate and return a new Rectangle. It could be reconsidered if and only if there's effectively a proven bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration and definition of `setLengthandWidth`, `setLength`, and `setWidth` methods, you specify that they return a `float` data type :

```cpp
//In header
float setLengthAndWidth(float, float);
float setLength(float Length);
float setWidth(float Width);

//In CPP file
float Rectangle::setLengthAndWidth(float Len, float Wid)
{
    setLength(Len);
    setWidth(Wid);
}
float Rectangle::setLength(float length)
{
    if (length >= 0 || length <= 20.0)
        length = length;
    else
        length = 1.0;
}
float Rectangle::setWidth(float width)
{
    if (width >= 0 || width <= 20.0)
        width = width;
    else
        width = 1.0;
}
```

If you want to not get that error, change the data type from `float` to `void` in the method declaration and definitions, like this :

```cpp
//In header
void setLengthAndWidth(float, float);
void setLength(float Length);
void setWidth(float Width);

//In CPP file
void Rectangle::setLengthAndWidth(float Len, float Wid)
{
    setLength(Len);
    setWidth(Wid);
}
void Rectangle::setLength(float length)
{
    if (length >= 0 || length <= 20.0)
        length = length;
    else
        length = 1.0;
}
void Rectangle::setWidth(float width)
{
    if (width >= 0 || width <= 20.0)
        width = width;
    else
        width = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, why do i get a downvote on my answer even if it gives the solution to the question ? I don't understand...

Comment: I will be rating you positive as you did answer my question. Not sure who voted down the whole post. My program now executes; however my window closes instantly. Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks you very much, and yes, i think i have an idea. Are you on a Windows OS ?

Comment: Ok, so add this line of code `system("pause")` as the end of your main function, so just before closing, the program will wait a user input via the keyboard

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep working on it. I have to figure out why it's not prompting my user for the data.

Comment: It's because you only ask for user input in `getLength` and `getWidth` methods, which are never called

Answer (score 0):

Why does your `getLength` and `getWidth` methods modify values? Generally accessor methods are only supposed return the appropriate fields.

HatsuPointerKun is correct though.

The methods have a return type of float but fail to return any value.
Either have them return a float number (most likely whatever you set them to) or change the return type to void.